# Using external Jar dependency in Eclipse with Non-Runnable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, japplet

I am making a Jar file in Eclipse to run an Applet, and the program uses an external jar file (jxl.jar). When I run the applet, it tells me it can't find the jxl files I am trying to use.

When I make the jar file, I right click the project and select Export and then JAR file. I don't see an option in the dialog that comes up to include dependencies. How can I ensure that it is including my external jar file, which is added to the external Java Build Path as an External Jar file in my Project Properties.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

- Specify the dependent JAR in the "archive" parameter; e.g.

  ```
  ARCHIVE="myapplet.jar,jxl.jar"
  ```
- Specify the dependent JAR in the manifest of your applet JAR; e.g. in the manifest.mf file add this line:

  ```
  Class-Path: jxl.jar
  ```