# Scene Builder - Importing Jars with Dependencies

Tags: java, import, jar, dependencies, scenebuilder

I am trying to import a .jar file into Scene Builder and Scene Builder tells me that it cannot find any UI components in the jar. I can import a different jar which works fine. The only real difference I notice between these is that the one I cannot import is dependent on the one I can import. I understand that I need to export this dependency with my jar but how do I do that if I do not want my jar to be a runnable jar?

I can use my custom component in Java code and it shows me the expected results but I cannot import it to Scene Builder if I export it to a jar.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Eclipse Oxygen.

EDIT: I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060520/using-external-jar-dependency-in-eclipse-with-non-runnable-jar) but I do not quite understand it.

Comment: what is the name of jar file (Library) you are trying to add is it exist on the internet or it's custom

Comment: Everything is completely custom.

Comment: sounds you need to combine the dependent components you are using in your jar file.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Should I hard code the components I depend on in my existing project?

Comment: Yes or you can combine the dependent jars then compile your file into one file